# Diagnosing Azure stateful actors

Tags: azure, actor, azure-service-fabric, stateful

I'm still trying to get my mind around [Azure Service Fabric Stateful Actors](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction/). So, my (current) problem is best put into an example like this:

- I've got a helpdesk system, where each ticket is a stateful actor. The actor knows about the state it's in (posted, dealt with, rejected, ...), can access the associated data and all that.
- I find I have made a mistake and a bunch of those 50.000 tickets are in the wrong state. So, I need to

  - fix the code
  - publish the solution
  - fix the data content of a subset of those 50.000 actors.

Now, how can I query the state of those actors, like "give me each actor that is in "rejected" and belongs to a user whose name starts with a german ümlaut"? How can I then patch the state data of those actors?

Do I really have to add a query method to each actor and wake up each single actor? Or is there a way to query those state dictionaries outside of the actors sitting on top of them?

Comment: I assume this is in regards to Service Fabric?

Comment: Yes. Those ones here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction/

Comment: i dont know enough to help you about fabric, but i recommend you to take a look at this blogger http://vunvulearadu.blogspot.com.ar/ its a MVP with a lot of post related with fabric and azure, im starting learning from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, in a situation like that you'd have to wake up each single actor (eventually).

If you are already in that state, I think JoshL's suggestion makes sense.

To avoid this sort of situations, you could keep an index dictionary in a stateful service, holding the information you'll want to query on e.g. the actor id and the status (posted, dealt with, etc.). You then only have to wake up those actors that are relevant.

There are two approaches you can take for that:

- Have the stateful service direct the flow of information - be responsible for updating the index dictionary and telling actors what to do (e.g. change status).
- Have the actors responsible for notifying the stateful service for state updates (this could be done periodically through reminders for example).

Comment: You know, all of this is quite far removed from the ease with which I cna do that with a nbormal SQL based solution: Do a select to ficure out the extend of the problem, write an update script that fixes it in one atomic transaction, run the script while deploying he new actor code. Can't say I'm happy about this. I mean, actors are parallel and nice and all that but fixing stuff is a real life situation in which they apparently fail dismally. :-(

Comment: @Volker I was wondering that myself. As a developer, I get some comfort from knowing that if I somehow destroy everything, at least I still have the data. With Actors, it's like the data is all over the place in small objects that I can only access with a working system. I am still learning about Azure Fabric, but I hope I can come to some understanding about best practices to address this concern.

Comment: Good point. What happens to the state of a stateful actor if it dies upon activation? I just hope it doesn't get deleted...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could consider overriding OnActivateAsync in your actor class(es) and implement the cleanup logic there, then upgrade your SF application?

This would prevent the need to iterate every single instance externally (as the SF runtime will call OnActivateAsync for you), and would ensure that the logic runs for each instance only if/when needed (only upon next activation for a given instance).

[more on Actor activate/deactivate/etc.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle/)

Best of luck!

Comment: So, basically, over the lifetime of the product (likely many years) actors would acquire a big tail of patch logic and version checking. Can't say I'm excited about that. I'm starting to wonder whether it's possible to a) access the table storage behind the actors or b) use sql server as storage provider. Or maybe go stateless altogether.

Comment: I think there is support for custom state providers, so that might be an option... though likely a complex one. Remember that a big selling point of stateful actors is auto replication of state changes to all nodes in the cluster. That's not likely something you'll a) easily build yourself or b) easily implement in a custom provider. Of course, of you don't need it, then maybe stateless is you best option.